# SqlDataAdapter.Update truncates doubles to ints back in sql table

Tags: sql, ado.net

I am manipulating data in a `DataTable`, and then calling `SqlDataAdapter.Update()` to put the data back into the SQL DB. It mostly works - except I can see that right before I call `Update()`, the numbers in certain columns in the `DataTable` have decimal parts, but then after `Update()` I look in the SQL table and the fractional part of the number has been lopped off, and the values are all integers.

The original `DataTable` was created by `SqlDataAdpater.Fill()`, and `SqlCommandBuilder` was used to create the default Update/Insert/Delete commands. The select statement to fill the `DataTable` only consisted of one SQL table. The relevant SQL table column data type is `decimal`, and I confirmed that was the type of the column in the `DataTable`.

Any suggestions as to what I am missing here? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Look at the DataAdapter's UpdateCommand's paramater collection to see what [`Scale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx) this field has. I assume it's 0 instead of 2.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yes, my SQL DB column was set as decimal(18,0) - after switching to (9,4) I am getting the SQL table populated correctly.  Why don't you write that as an answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>As requested, my comment as answer:</sub>

Look at the `DataAdapter`'s `UpdateCommand`'s parameter-collection to see what [`Scale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.scale.aspx) this field has. I assume it's 0 instead of 2 (your number of decimal places).  Change it accordingly then.